# XGBoost - select tree with the highest accuracy

Tags: python, decision-tree, xgboost

I need to visualize XGBoost's effects and I want to extract a single tree from it that has the highest accuracy on the test set. Is is built in in any way, or do I have to test by hand all of the trees? I'm using the Python version.

Comment: Please include more details.

Comment: I have XGBoost model. I want to extract a single tree. That tree has to have the highest accuracy of all trees on the test set. Do I have to check all trees one by one, or can I do it easier?

Comment: Which framework are you using?

Comment: Official XGBoost implementation for Python

Comment: I think that you will have to inspect them manually: model.get_booster().get_dump()

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to inspect individual trees in a tree ensemble model, then you should consider switching from a boosting-type algorithm (eg. XGBoost, LightGBM, GBM) to a bagging-type algorithm (eg. Random Forest).

By definition, the bagging algorithm grows trees in decreasing "smartness" order. In this case, the highest accuracy tree model is probably the first one in the XGBoost tree ensemble.